# how do you use loops? and when?

Tags: python

Im struggling to use while so i want to ask here for clarity and help on use of it.
Because i am quite new to coding so i dont fully understand when to use them.
So it could turn out that i need to use something else but i just need something to loop or return to the start of the wolf.

```
print(r"""        _
       / \      _-'
     _/|  \-''- _ /
__-' { |          \
    /             \
    /       "o.  |o }
    |            \ ;
                  ',
       \_         __\
         ''-_    \.//
           / '-____'
          /
        _'
      _-'""")


w=int(input("woof do you want to play a game?\n1)Yes\n2)No\n"))

if w > 2:
  print("Invalid character")
  input("woof do you want to play a game?\n1)Yes\n2)No\n")

if w == 1:
  print("Then lets play heads or tails")
else:
  quit
ans=int(input("What do you choose?\n1)Heads\n2)Tails\n"))


if ans > 2:
  print("Invalid character")
  input("What do you choose?\n1)Heads\n2)Tails\n")

if ans == 1:
  print("Oh so you have chosen Heads")
if ans == 2:
  print("Oh so you have chosen Tails")

coin=random.randint(1,2)


if ans == coin:
  print(r"""                     .
                    / V\
                  / `  /
                 <<   |
                 /    |
               /      |
             /        |
           /    \  \ /
          (      ) | |
  ________|   _/_  | |
<__________\______)\__)      
Oh no you have Won""")


if ans != coin:
  print("I have won this game")
  
red=int(input("Would you like to play again?\n1)Yes\n2)No\n"))
```

Comment: usually for user input you would use `while` because you want to get user input at some point and `for` loops can loop only so much while `while` loops can be infinite

Comment: Looping is a "repetition" construct. You use them when you want to repeat things.

Comment: "So it could turn out that i need to use for but i just need something to loop to the start of the wolf." I'm sorry, but this doesn't make sense. I understand communication might be difficult when you are new to this, but please try to elaborate on what you are saying here

Comment: You can put every thing after first `print("...")`, inside a while loop : `while ans != 'No':`. 
That way, you will break the loop when user ansers `No`, else loop will continue.

Comment: @Matiiss well, for-loops can be infinite as well. The old-school "while loops are for indeterminate looping, for loops are for when you know the number of loops" is not quite accurate, more precisely for languages like Python with iterator- based for-loops, for loops are for things that are easy to express with iterators, whiles loops are for the other cases EDIT: BUT that is not a terrible heuristic for people learning

Comment: `while` iterates until a condition is true (which may or may not ever happen); `for` iterates over a sequence (which may or may not produce a finite number of values).

Comment: @user3840170 I'm only trying to get an opinion of what I should use here and how I should go about it because I am unsure what I should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would recommend. You could put the entire thing in the while loop, but even then you would at least want your ascii art to be outside of it for tabbing purposes.

```py
def wolf():
    global begin_wolf, win_wolf
    print(begin_wolf)


    w=int(input("woof do you want to play a game?\n1)Yes\n2)No\n"))

    if w > 2:
        print("Invalid character")
        input("woof do you want to play a game?\n1)Yes\n2)No\n")

    if w == 1:
        print("Then lets play heads or tails")
    else:
        quit
    ans=int(input("What do you choose?\n1)Heads\n2)Tails\n"))


    if ans > 2:
        print("Invalid character")
        input("What do you choose?\n1)Heads\n2)Tails\n")

    if ans == 1:
        print("Oh so you have chosen Heads")
    if ans == 2:
        print("Oh so you have chosen Tails")

    coin=random.randint(1,2)


    if ans == coin:
        print(win_wolf)


    if ans != coin:
        print("I have won this game")
  

begin_wolf = r"""        _
       / \      _-'
     _/|  \-''- _ /
__-' { |          \
    /             \
    /       "o.  |o }
    |            \ ;
                  ',
       \_         __\
         ''-_    \.//
           / '-____'
          /
        _'
      _-'"""
win_wolf = r"""                     .
                    / V\
                  / `  /
                 <<   |
                 /    |
               /      |
             /        |
           /    \  \ /
          (      ) | |
  ________|   _/_  | |
<__________\______)\__)      
Oh no you have Won"""

red = 1
while red == 1:
    wolf()
    red = int(input("Would you like to play again?\n1)Yes\n2)No\n"))
```